# Trying to get Window key and pause key to work together

Tags: windows

I am trying to get the system properties window pop up by sending the window key (`left` or `right`) and the `pause/break` key

This is what I have been trying:

```
Send, {LWin Down}{Pause}{LWin Up}
```

But to no effect. Any help please?

Comment: I've given an "answer" that doesn't directly answer your question, but would if you'd instead asked "how do I programmatically open the system properties window?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to invoke a short-cut, why not ask the control panel to open it? Run the following:

```
control /name Microsoft.System
```

[Executing Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and the linked to [Canonical Names of Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))